# Reliability of DPM with Windows Storage Server or large backups

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup, scdpm

We are successfully using DPM 2010 in a number of places, but in two sites we've been struggling with getting the backups to work. Both sites are backing up about 1TB of data and both from Windows Storage Server 2008 boxes. They both constantly get errors like this:

"The replica of Volume D:\ on servername.domain.tld is not consistent with the protected data source. DPM error ID = 33123. (ID 33123)"

When we perform a consistency check, that can run for nearly two days before failing.

Anyone have experience of backing up WSS with DPM and it working without problems?

Thanks.

Comment: BTW, error ID 33123 is not listed on technet in the DPM 2007 or DPM 2010 Error Code Catalogue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Answer my own question having created Microsoft Support Cases to solve both sites it turns out that the backup servers were set up correctly but the networking is absolutely vital - including the networking drivers on both NICs.
Also set throttling to about 80% of your maximum network speed which helped me.